# Can a bundle be passed to a service?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

In my application i need to get a value from an activity to a service. The value that i need to retrieve is the one i clicked in that activity.

For eg: If i select x[i] element from Activity A, i need to retrieve the value x[i] in a Service S.

How is it possible?

Thanks,

Niki

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the service use this:

```
public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
     super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
     Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
}
```

Comment: @niki sorry, its int. You should avoid copy-pasting. Real programmer type code. and then they solve errors. ;)

Comment: Corrections would help others who check out.

Answer (score 2):

When you create an intent , you can put data to it and the same data will be transferred along with the Intent when you start the service.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Class) ;
intent.putExtra(key, value);

startService(intent);
```

In the receiving end get the intent and get extra value from it.

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtra();
b.get<ValueType>(key);
```

Comment: I cudn't find getIntent() in my Service.

Comment: You find getIntent() if the receiving part is an Activity. Here in my case its a Service.

Comment: @Niki, Bundle b = getIntent().getExtra(); b.getXXX(key); is to be called inside the onStart / onCreate methods of the receiving service class.

Comment: @Vinay: I got the right answer. Thanks. In Service in onCreate it was not working. But it works in onStartCommand.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)` method in the service.